# having 2 instances of the same script on one page without conflict

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have 2 forms on one page. both of which have an option to select the number of fields via a drop down.

I use the same JQuery and essentially the same HTML on each form and have changed the form IDs slightly but this does not seem to help anything.

```js
getPagination('#table-id');
jQuery('#maxRows').trigger('change');

function getPagination(table) {

  jQuery('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
    jQuery('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination div
    var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter 
    var maxRows = parseInt(jQuery(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option

    var totalRows = jQuery(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows 
    jQuery(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter 
      if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows

        jQuery(this).hide(); // fade it out 
      }
      if (trnum <= maxRows) {
        jQuery(this).show();
      } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
    }); //  was fade out to fade it in 
    if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
      var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..  
      // numbers of pages 
      for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li 
        jQuery('.pagination').append('<li data-page="' + i + '">\
                                  <span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
                                </li>').show();
      } // end for i 


    } // end if row count > max rows
    jQuery('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li 


    //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL DEFAULT
    showig_rows_count(maxRows, 1, totalRows);
    //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL DEFAULT

    jQuery('.pagination li').on('click', function(e) { // on click each page
      e.preventDefault();
      var pageNum = jQuery(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
      var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
      jQuery('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li 
      jQuery(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked 


      //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL
      showig_rows_count(maxRows, pageNum, totalRows);
      //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL



      jQuery(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
        trIndex++; // tr index counter 
        // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
        if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
          jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
          jQuery(this).show();
        } //else fade in 
      }); // end of for each tr in table
    }); // end of on click pagination list
  });
  // end of on select change 

  // END OF PAGINATION 

}


// All Table search script
function FilterkeyWord_all_table() {

  // Count td if you want to search on all table instead of specific column

  var count = jQuery('.table').children('tbody').children('tr:first-child').children('td').length;

  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search_input_all");
  var input_value = document.getElementById("search_input_all").value;
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  if (input_value != '') {
    table = document.getElementById("table-id");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {

      var flag = 0;

      for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
        if (td) {

          var td_text = td.innerHTML;
          if (td.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            //var td_text = td.innerHTML;  
            //td.innerHTML = 'shaban';
            flag = 1;
          } else {
            //DO NOTHING
          }
        }
      }
      if (flag == 1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } else {
    //RESET TABLE
    jQuery('#maxRows').trigger('change');
  }
}

getPagination('#table-id2');
jQuery('#maxRows2').trigger('change');

function getPagination(table) {

  jQuery('#maxRows2').on('change', function() {
    jQuery('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination div
    var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter 
    var maxRows2 = parseInt(jQuery(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option

    var totalRows = jQuery(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows 
    jQuery(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter 
      if (trnum > maxRows2) { // if tr number gt maxRows2

        jQuery(this).hide(); // fade it out 
      }
      if (trnum <= maxRows2) {
        jQuery(this).show();
      } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
    }); //  was fade out to fade it in 
    if (totalRows > maxRows2) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
      var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows2); // ceil total(rows/maxrows2) to get ..  
      // numbers of pages 
      for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li 
        jQuery('.pagination').append('<li data-page="' + i + '">\
                                    <span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
                                  </li>').show();
      } // end for i 


    } // end if row count > max rows
    jQuery('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li 


    //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL DEFAULT
    showig_rows_count(maxRows2, 1, totalRows);
    //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL DEFAULT

    jQuery('.pagination li').on('click', function(e) { // on click each page
      e.preventDefault();
      var pageNum = jQuery(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
      var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
      jQuery('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li 
      jQuery(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked 


      //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL
      showig_rows_count(maxRows2, pageNum, totalRows);
      //SHOWING ROWS NUMBER OUT OF TOTAL



      jQuery(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
        trIndex++; // tr index counter 
        // if tr index gt maxRows2*pageNum or lt maxRows2*pageNum-maxRows2 fade if out
        if (trIndex > (maxRows2 * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows2 * pageNum) - maxRows2)) {
          jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
          jQuery(this).show();
        } //else fade in 
      }); // end of for each tr in table
    }); // end of on click pagination list
  });
  // end of on select change 

  // END OF PAGINATION 

}





//ROWS SHOWING FUNCTION
function showig_rows_count(maxRows2, pageNum, totalRows) {
  //Default rows showing
  var end_index = maxRows2 * pageNum;
  var start_index = ((maxRows2 * pageNum) - maxRows2) + parseFloat(1);
  var string = 'Showing ' + start_index + ' to ' + end_index + ' of ' + totalRows + ' entries';
  jQuery('.rows_count').html(string);
}

// All Table search script
function FilterkeyWord_all_table() {

  // Count td if you want to search on all table instead of specific column

  var count = jQuery('.table').children('tbody').children('tr:first-child').children('td').length;

  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search_input_all");
  var input_value = document.getElementById("search_input_all").value;
  filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  if (input_value != '') {
    table = document.getElementById("table-id2");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {

      var flag = 0;

      for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
        if (td) {

          var td_text = td.innerHTML;
          if (td.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            //var td_text = td.innerHTML;  
            //td.innerHTML = 'shaban';
            flag = 1;
          } else {
            //DO NOTHING
          }
        }
      }
      if (flag == 1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  } else {
    //RESET TABLE
    jQuery('#maxRows2').trigger('change');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <div class="col-md-12 collection colwrapper">
    <div class="colelement">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header_wrap">
          <div class="num_rows">
            <div class="form-group">
              <!--  Show Numbers Of Rows   -->
              <select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-class" id="table-id">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:100%;">Collections</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> One 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Two 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Three 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Four 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Five 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Six 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Seven 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Eight 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Nine 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Ten 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 deldeets delwrapper">
    <div class="delelement">
      <div class="col-md-12 deldeets delwrapper">
        <div class="delelement">
          ​​
          <div class="container">
            <div class="header_wrap">
              <div class="num_rows">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!--  Show Numbers Of Rows   -->
                  <select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows2">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-class" id="table-id2">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width:100%;">Deliveries</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> One 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Two 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Three 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Four 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Five 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Six 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Seven 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Eight 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Nine 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Ten 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

You will see from the code above that the HTML and JQuery are almost identical. I have changed ids from "table-id" to "table-id2" in the bottom HTML snippet and replicated this in the JQuery and also "maxrow" to "maxrow2"

You will see though that if you run the code that the top drop down does not do anything and the bottom drop-down controls the two forms.

Probably a simple fix but I cannot see what I need to change. Any help would be great

What confuses me though, is its the dropdown where I have added the "2" after the IDs that seems to control both tables. Id have thought that if any, the original ID would have worked

Comment: I tried to answer your question, but I don't feel like I really understand what you want - what would be the expected / accepted event for your code?

Answer (score 0):

What about this simpler code? Maybe this helps you out.

```js
// this is a VERY basic state management object
// I initialized it with 1 (not 0, as for array numbers), because
// it shows "how many tds I want to display"
const tableRows = {
  table1: 1,
  table2: 1
}

function showRows(tableId, numRows) {
  // I edited the selector, it controls tds now, not divs
  jQuery(tableId + " tbody tr td").each(function(index, item) {
    if (index + 1 > numRows) {
      jQuery(item).css("display", "none");
    } else {
      jQuery(item).css("display", "block");
    }
  });
}

// these two functions display the initially displayed tds
showRows('#table-id', tableRows.table1);
showRows('#table-id2', tableRows.table2);

// this controls the first table's tds
jQuery("#maxRows").on('change', function(e) {
  tableRows.table1 = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  showRows("#table-id", tableRows.table1);
});

// this controls the second table's tds
jQuery("#maxRows2").on('change', function(e) {
  tableRows.table2 = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  showRows("#table-id2", tableRows.table2);
});
```

```css
/* I added this CSS classes so the base state of the
tds are "hidden" and not "displayed", so it doesn't
flicker on startup */

#table-id tbody tr td,
#table-id2 tbody tr td {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <div class="col-md-12 collection colwrapper">
    <div class="colelement">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header_wrap">
          <div class="num_rows">
            <div class="form-group">
              <!--  Show Numbers Of Rows   -->
              <select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-class" id="table-id">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="width:100%;">Collections</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> One 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Two 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Three 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Four 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Five 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Six 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Seven 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Eight 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Nine 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                  <label> Ten 
                                            
                                    </label>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 deldeets delwrapper">
    <div class="delelement">
      <div class="col-md-12 deldeets delwrapper">
        <div class="delelement">
          ​​
          <div class="container">
            <div class="header_wrap">
              <div class="num_rows">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <!--  Show Numbers Of Rows   -->
                  <select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows2">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-striped table-class" id="table-id2">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width:100%;">Deliveries</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> One 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Two 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Three 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Four 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Five 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Six 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Seven 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Eight 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Nine 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="col-md-12 special-hidden_fields">
                      <label> Ten 
                                            
                                    </label>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Please pay attention to the **VERY basic state management object** (`const tableRows = {}`) - this may come in handy, when you want to upload data to a server based on rows displayed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. much simpler than what I had lol and seems to do what I am looking for on here when I run the code. It does not however, seem to work on my site. all of the rows are open and the drop down appears to do nothing :-(

Comment: Ideally I want the top rows to be controlled the first drop down and the second to be controlled by the second drop down. In my code, both were controlled by the second drop down. your code seems to work better here but not on my site for some reason. . My example above has hone <div> per <td> however live there is more divs inside. When run on codepen, again it works but it seems to control the divs rather than the tds

Comment: Yes, the code I wrote display or hides the **div**s, not the **tds**. From what you wrote in your comments I deduce that something on your site doesn't let this code run (usually this is an error in JS).

Comment: If the **div**s stay displayed (that's their base state), then the code doesn't run (on your site). Actually it should be reversed: the base state should be "hidden" and the **td**s to show should be displayed. I'll add commentes to my snippet, so you see what SHOULD happen at a certain step.

Comment: And to make your code simpler: extract identical steps into groups (functions, objects, arrays). Actually the jQuery **change** handler could be done in one (for any number of similarly structured dropdowns and tables), but I thought I just do it fast :)

Comment: Ive sorted my code, there was a slight error in the html. but I still cant get it to work. The row one shows fine but the drop down isnt changing the number of rows displayed

Comment: Do you have your WHOLE code where I could look at it? I'm sure it should work OK... :)

Comment: Sorry... I have found the problem... Wordpress is very temperamental. In the JQuery there was 2 x " $(this)" which I changed to "JQuery(this)" works perfect now. thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I'm happy that I could help! :D